# CSS Responsive text over images in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I have a flexbox full of images that will all have text over the top them. I am stuck at trying to get the text to be responsive. The text needs to stay inside of the div and resize with the image. Anyone have any tips or tricks on how to best accomplish this? My full code example is linked below.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row">
  <div class="flex-column">
            <div class=" welcome overlay-parent">   
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/548x227">
                    <div class="overlay-text"><h1>Welcome to My Place</h1></div>
                </div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/548x459"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div><img src="http://placehold.it/812x459"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="feature-about overlay-parent">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/406x227">
                <div class="overlay-text"><h2>About Something</h2>
                    <p>It’s the latest lorem ipsum dolor sit brief intro to the park goes here. ounded in 2016. It’s the latest lorem ipsum dolor sit brief intro to the park goes here. </p> </div>
      </div>
          <div><img src="http://placehold.it/406x227"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row row">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/812x459"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/548x459"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/enigmas2/pen/ygKmGX

Comment: Use media queries to control the font size

Comment: I was heading in that direction @ZimSystem but wanted to see if there were options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use viewport units. Those will scale with the viewport as it resizes.

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
:root {font-size: calc(1vw + .1vmin);}
.container{
  max-width: 1360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img{
  border:2px solid white;
}

.flex-row {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column{
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1360px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay-parent {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:  0;
  width: 100%;
 }

.welcome h1 {
  padding: 20px 0 0 25px;
  line-height: .8em;
  font-size: 5em;

}

.feature-about h2, p {
 padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4/foundation.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row">
  <div class="flex-column">
   <div class=" welcome overlay-parent"> 
      <img src="http://placehold.it/548x227">
     <div class="overlay-text"><h1>Welcome to My Place</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/548x459"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div><img src="http://placehold.it/812x459"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="feature-about overlay-parent">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/406x227">
         <div class="overlay-text"><h2>About Something</h2>
     <p>It’s the latest lorem ipsum dolor sit brief intro to the park goes here. ounded in 2016. It’s the latest lorem ipsum dolor sit brief intro to the park goes here. </p> </div>
      </div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/406x227"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row row">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/812x459"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/548x459"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boom! That is slick @Michael!

Comment: @Johanna it's the new hotness fo sho! makes responsive text easy.

Comment: Mind eq blown! Thank you!

Comment: I'll officially accept your answer as soon as stackO's time limit is up. lol

Comment: @MichaelCoker Hey do you mind if I borrow your CSS? Combining Flex and Boostrap has been a real pain.

Comment: @scoopzilla what do you mean can you borrow my CSS? If you  mean that `:root` entry, of course. And you can google and find tons of techniques like that. I tend to use this in my boilerplate, which takes into account viewport width and height `:root {font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + .5vmin);}`

Comment: I was not aware of the `vw` attribute. LOVE it.

Comment: The Flex and Foundation code is credit to @serg-chernata

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining your font sizes in relation to the width of the viewport. For example, try setting `font-size: 5vw` on your `H1`.